# "Cannot read property "0" from undefined" for Google Books API

Tags: javascript, api, typeerror

In my `script.js` for a Google Book API search web app, with few cases I encounter the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

And this is referring to the following code line:

```
isbn = data.items[i].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier;
```

So, is there a way to avoid this error and check if `industryIdentifiers` exist in the data returned from the query before assigning the variable?

I tried checking first if `industryIdentifiers` exists and then assign the value to the variable, checking if `industryIdentifiers` is null or "undefined" before assigning it, but I cannot solve this problem.

This is the code that I am using at the moment:

```
/*global document, $, console, event, results */

function bookSearch() {                          //function triggered by button
    /* eslint-disable no-console */
    event.preventDefault();                      //preventing auto refresh of the page
    //console.log("This function is working.");  //console.log to see if the function was running properly

    var search = document.getElementById('book').value; //storing the value of search
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = '';  
    //console.log(search);                       //console.log to see "search" in console 

    $.ajax({

        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + search + "&startIndex=0&maxResults=40&key=AIzaSyCOBbymaad4eBVNFVF5JC-Pc0TQzE6AHOw", //linking API + our search
        //-------------^this increments the number of results returned. default 10
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            //var results = document.getElementById('results');  //creating variable results

            //var title,authors, publisher,link,thumbNail,isbn = ''; //variables to use in results.innerHTML

            for (i = 0 ; i < data.items.length ; i++ ) {
                         //-------------^loop runs as much as the lenght of items
                title = data.items[i].volumeInfo.title;              //storing informations to display
                authors = data.items[i].volumeInfo.authors;
                link = data.items[i].volumeInfo.infoLink;
                thumbNail = data.items[i].volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail;

                if( typeof data.items[i].volumeInfo.publisher != "undefined"){
                    publisher = data.items[i].volumeInfo.publisher;

                }

                isbn = data.items[i].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier;

                results.innerHTML += "<h2>" + title + "</h2>" +      //writing the results returned 
                                     "<h3>By: " + authors + "</h3>" 
                if(publisher != null){                               //this solves the problem of showing 

                    results.innerHTML += "<h3>Published by: " + publisher + "</h3>"   

                 }  
                 results.innerHTML += "<a href=" + link +'"><img src="'+ thumbNail + '"></a>' +
                 "<h4>ISBN " + isbn + "</h4>" +    
                 "<hr><br>"



            }  
        },

    type: "GET"

    })

}
```

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(data.items[i].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers)`?

Comment: Can you show the JSON string under volumeInfo property when you get the error, vs when you don't get the error?

Comment: The result of that console.log is undefined.
But even with a solution like
 if ( data.items[i].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers !="undefined"){
        isbn = data.items[i].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier;
 }
I still receive the error message.

Comment: When console.log(data.items[i].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers) works correctly, I receive 
0:
identifier: "9781781106945"
type: "ISBN_13"
__proto__: Object
1:
identifier: "1781106940"
type: "ISBN_10"

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the actual data you receive when there's an error vs. when there is no error, here's how you could prevent the exception:

```
if (data.items[i].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers 
        && data.items[i].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0]) {
    isbn = data.items[i].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier;
}
```

If you are not sure about `volumeInfo` property, you can even add that to be checked:

```
if (data.items[i].volumeInfo 
        && data.items[i].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers 
        && data.items[i].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0]) {
    isbn = data.items[i].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier;
}
```

This basically checks that "industryIdentifiers" is not null, and that it has a zeroth element in it. You are probably missing to check the second part when you tried.

*Please add the actual response you get at the time of error and when it is successful if even this solution doesn't work.*

Comment: Checking the existence of data.items[i] and the other statements seems working. 
But now when i print "isbn", if it is not defined because is not existing, I see the error Uncaught ReferenceError: isbn is not defined

To solve this I should use a statement like

Comment: @EdoardoTrotta I didn't realize you haven't initialized `isbn` variable. You should put a statement at the top to initialize all variables. Something like `var isbn = ""`